# How to add custom webpart property to existing category (Appearance)?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I add custom property for my web part. How to add this property in existing category (Appearance). I try set attribute [Category("Appearance")] but in this case my property is in "Miscellaneous" category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, you must add it to your own category, not to one of the built-in ones.